# How can I create test report in excel directly in watir?

Tags: ruby, excel, watir

All the comments showing on command prompt that all comments with specification should directly entered into the excel sheet so it will directly create test run

Comment: if this question is resolved please choose an answer and mark it as correct by clicking the checkmark icon

Answer (score 1):

Most users handle results reporting via using another [framework](http://watir.com/frameworks/) (mini-test, testunit, rspec, cucumber, or a variety of watir-specific framworks that use one of those) that has reporting capabilities and automagically generates results for all validation steps that are using 'asserts' or 'shoulds'.

Alternatively you can roll your own reporting, via XML, HTML or some other means.  For example if you wanted to write to Excel you would mostly likely make use of the 'ROO' Gem that is designed to interface with excel files.

[This example](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+report+class) and [another example](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+report+class+%28version+2%29) of doing your own HTML reporting can be found in the [examples](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/Examples) on the Watir Wiki.

ALL of that is done via Ruby, the underlying language that Watir is coded in.  So really this is a question to ask in a Ruby forum.

Answer (score 0):

[Watir](http://watir.com/) drives browsers. It does not even know there is a thing called Excel. But, since Watir is implemented in Ruby, you can use another Ruby gem to create Excel files. One of them is [roo](http://roo.rubyforge.org/). I did not use it, but as far as I can see you can even create Excel files without having Excel installed.